# How can authenticate user by only ip address in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have table with users. There is "ip_address" column in this table.

I have server - java server
I have web app on spring boot.

Spring boot communicates with java server by rest.

I need realize authonticate user in system by ip. 
Whem user open web page - spring boot app get remoteIpAddress(`String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();`) and pass it to java server in url. java server ckeck this ip in db in table users and if user can login return this user to spring boot app.

I want realize this with spring security. But when i open web page, in browser opened dialog window for input login and password. But I do not need login and password. I need if user is not null - give access to pages and save the user.

and if I input login and password and press "ok" button I move to my `IPAddressBasedAuthenticationProvider`

```
@Component
public class IPAddressBasedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        AuthLkUser authLkUserByIp = authService.getAuthLkUserByIp(ipAddress);

        if (authLkUserByIp == null) return null;

        boolean b = authService.checkAuthLkUser(authLkUserByIp);
        if (b) return null;
        final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        grantedAuths.add(grantedAuthority);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in this class saved user to session. And after that when I open web pages i not need input login and password. it contains in session. but my wep page not openned with error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jul 11 14:27:59 ALMT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied
```

Comment: No configuration, no stack trace. Have you actually debugged your code? Also imho it is a terrible idea to inject the `HttpServletRequest` to obtain the information you need. It is part of the `WebAuthenticatioNDetails` which is set on the `Authentication`, use that instead. Also not sure if authentication based on IP-address is a good idea, what about large corporations, generally they only have a single external IP-address due to a proxy everyone uses.

Answer (score 2):

For **Spring Boot applications** that run with the embedded Apache Tomcat container,  you can use the org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter  from Apache Tomcat.

```
 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean remoteAddressFilter() {
  FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
  RemoteAddrFilter filter = new RemoteAddrFilter();
 // filter.setAllow("127.0.0.1");
  filter.setAllow("127\\.0\\.0\\.1");
  filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
  filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/gs/serving-web-content/testParameters");
  return filterRegistrationBean;
 }
```

> **allow :**    A regular expression (using java.util.regex) that the remote
>   client's IP address is compared to. If this attribute is specified,
>   the remote address MUST match for this request to be accepted. If this
>   attribute is not specified, all requests will be accepted UNLESS the
>   remote address matches a deny pattern.

You can refer this article - [How do I restrict access to my application by IP address?](https://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/82126495-How-do-I-restrict-access-to-my-application-by-IP-address-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Expression-Based Access Control** provided by Spring. To secure individual URL, you are able to do something like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
    ...
  </http>
```

Where you created expression like if he has role admin and his IP address is xxx.xxx.x.x, then it is allowed. So you are looking for `hasIpAddress`.
More about expression-based access control is in their [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

If you want to create this restrictions for Spring Boot and if you are using Apache Tomcat, then you are able to  to enable a Servlet Filter ([here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) is description) and then you can just enable **Remote Address Filter** and then set addresses which you want to allow. More abouy this filter is in Apache Tomcat [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter).

And another one option is that if you will use Spring Security. [There is](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html) class **WebAuthenticationDetails** which provide method *getRemoteAddress()*.

Comment: I saw this solution already but I do not know where is write this? I do not have web.xml

Comment: You dont have web.xml? Add more configurations and project structure to your question.

Comment: sorry, i saw only spring and not spring boot

Comment: Are you running on apache tomcat?

Comment: Ok, so then check my edit. You should use a Remote Address Filter class from apache tomcat

Comment: Oh, now I see this solution with WebAuthenticationDetails is already mentioned in comment from  M. Deinum!